# "especially" without meaning more so?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I want to say something along the lines of "We must protect everyone, especially children".

But this doesn't exactly work for what I want to say. Because I do not mean that children are MORE deserving of protection in this instance.

***How can I exemplify a group without raising them up to an elevated status?***

I thought of "in particular" but this has the same problem.

Comment: It's hard to know what you want to say. "Especially" does mean "moreso". Why are you mentioning children if you don't want to emphasise them? Maybe "for example children" or "including children" or in writing "(e.g. children)"?

Comment: Perhaps children was a bad example. Let's say there was some horrid criminal who had been maiming cats. The judge might say that he needs to impose a long sentence "to protect all animals, especially cats". But it's not like you want to say cats are more deserving of protection. You're just trying to say that cats are potentially in more danger. So I don't think "especially" works there.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum Love it! Thanks

Comment: The word especially is for emphasis; it does not raise anything "to an elevated level."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’d suggest “We must protect children and everyone else.”

Comment: +1 Yes, good rewrite; a technique not very appreciated around here.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to give prominence to a particular subset S₁ of S if you mention it at the expense of S₂, S₃ ... no matter how you phrase it.

To mitigate this. the reason why you're singling out S₁ (even if it's merely your chosen focus) has to be explained:

- 'We must protect everyone; this article deals with the protection of children ...'
- '... to protect all animals; cats are an obvious case in point at the moment'.